# How to replace placeholders in placeholders (variables) in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

In a Django template, I'd like to add text from a model field. This text field can be understood as text-template itself. It may look like:

```
Dear {{user}},
thank your for...
Regards,
  {{sender}}
```

This text field is available as `emailtemplate` inside a normal Django template. The fields from above (`user`=Joe, `sender`=Alice) are available as well.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

{{ emailtemplate }}    

{% endblock %}
```

The output shall be as follows

```
Dear Joe,
thank your for...
Regards,
  Alice
```

I have no clue how to do this with built-in methods. My only idea is to parse `emailtemplate` manually before I hand it over to the template engine, thus inside the view. But I'm sure, I'm not the first one with that problem.

Comment: I would write a custom template tag that basically uses ``jinja2.Template.render`` or ``django.template.Template.render`` with the current context data. But I wonder if someone else comes up with a more elegant solution.

Comment: I am wondering if this is not the solution you wanted or did you use another method to solve your described problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several reworks, I came up with the following solution. Double check who can modify/alter the template string since this could be a big security flaw, if alterable by the wrong people.

`views.py`:

```
class YourView(TemplateView):    
    template_name = 'page.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["emailtemplate"] = "Dear {{user}}, {{sender}}"
        context["user"] = "Joe"
        context["sender"] = "Alice"
        return context
```

`page.html`:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load core_tags %}

{% block content %}

{% foobar emailtemplate %}

{% endblock %}
```

`your_app/templatetags/core_tags.py` (don't forget the `__init__.py` file to ensure the directory is treated as a Python package `your_app` must also be in `INSTALLED_APPS`):

```
from django import template
from django.template import Template

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def foobar(context, ts):
    t = Template(template_string=ts)
    return t.render(context)
```

See also:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags

Comment: Thank you so much for this!! I store html markup within django models so that i can control how other users edit them. This now allows users to include merged fields in their markup. I was so close to asking my own questions for this, gladly found this page.